# spyOn response is coming back empty

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, spyon

```
it('should inject acaQQService and run getQQFormData', inject(
    [AcaQqService], (service: AcaQqService) => {
      const resp: QuickQuoteEntity  = <QuickQuoteEntity><unknown>[];
      spyOn(service, 'getQQFormData').and.returnValue(of(resp));
      expect(resp).not.toBeNull();
      console.log(resp);
    }));
```

When spying on this service call the data is coming back empty. The type conversion does not seem to be working for resp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `spyOn` installs a `spy` onto a method of an existing object but it doesn't invoke that method. Therefore, between installing the spy on the method `AcaQqService.getQQFormData` and invoking `expect`, you need to call `AcaQqService.getQQFormData`.

Also you don't check the result of `AcaQqService.getQQFormData` (an `Observable`) but the `resp` object defined inside the test. To make this work, it could be rewritten as follows.

```
spyOn(service, 'getQQFormData').and.returnValue(of(resp));
service.getQQFormData(...).subscribe(v => expect(v).toBe(resp));
```

*Such a test however wouldn't make sense because the tested method is mocked, hence no internals of the service are involved.*